# Loading all NodeJS node_modules from a zip in production

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm packaging a small project with already 30K files in node_modules. It's a real pain on Windows when installing or moving that project.

Is there a way to zip my node_modules and let require('') to seek in it ?

Comment: There are unzip modules available for gulp for which you could write a script. If you move the project to a different server, why don't you just run npm install instead of copying the node_modules?

Comment: are you not using npm ?

Comment: Have you check this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-folder

Comment: I use NPM on Linux with a package.json but for windows I rather use a big zip because it takes too much times, and some modules breaks, etc ... Nodewebkit do something like that

Answer (score -3):

You can use Node Package Manager (NPM).

You can install modules using

```
npm install <your_module_name> --save
```

This will create a `package.json` file which you will need later to download the modules.

When you want to download and install the modules you used, simply run the following command:

```
npm install
```

And include it in your code using

```
var your_module_name = require('your_module_name');
```

Comment: -1. The question is not asking for the basics of using modules, it's asking how they can be zipped up to reduce the performance penalty of moving 30,000 tiny files.